# Where-Object with Get-Content not working

Tags: powershell

I have a file, say `a.txt` with the following content:

```
STATUS
-----
Pending
```

I am running the following query:

```
Get-Content a.txt | Where-Object Status -Match 'Pending'
```

The above query returns nothing.

Adding to my requirement:

- I need to get the content in a variable, like

  `$contentOfFile = Get-Content a.txt`
- This variable is passed to a function that verifies if it has the match

  `$contentOfFile | **Where-Object Status -Match 'Pending'**`

Note: `Where-Object Status -Match 'Pending'` cannot be changed to `Select-String` because the function is used by many sources.

**FIX:**

```
$contentOfFile = ConvertFrom-Csv (Get-Content a.txt)
$contentOfFile | Where-Object Status -Match 'Pending'
```

Comment: What's with your note? So you wrote a not running script, one suggests you how to change it and you tell us, you can't change it? So, then your script won't ever work...

Comment: The note is to ensure we are dealing with the first part of the request and not the second part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `Get-Content` , the `STATUS` in your text file is stored as a plain text and not as a property. If you intend to use `Get-Content`, you can use `Select-String` cmdlet like

`Get-Content a.txt | Select-String -pattern 'Pending'`

But if you want to get the output as you desire, you can use the `Import-Csv`. What it will do is, it will make your `STATUS` as a `-Header` property and then you can use the `where-object` as you have used earlier. After all, a `csv` file is a text file, just comma-separated. Below works for me:-

`Import-Csv a.txt | Where-Object Status -Match 'Pending'`

Comment: Can we represent it like an xml and then call Where-Object.? I am new to Powershell, so could you help me in converting it to xml if possible.

Comment: @thepace `Get-Command -Noun xml` will give you all available xml commands. `Get-Help ConvertTo-Xml` will give you the help according help.

Comment: @Clijsters: I have udpated my query. Could you please help on that. I think XMl might not be required .

Comment: I think, @Vivek has answered your question, didn't he?

Comment: I tried this but it didnt work:  $a= Import-Csv a.txt; $a|Where-Object -match "Pending".   I need to pass the $a to a function that does the match; hence the above query.

Comment: You should read the explanation. The moment your `$a = Import-Csv a.txt` holds true, `STATUS` (in your text file) becomes a `-header` property. So you use, `$a | Where-Object status -Match 'Pending'`.

Comment: Regarding the XML representation, yes you can use `ConvertTo-Xml` cmdlet, but I highly doubt if `where-object` can be used . Something like this can be done - `(((Get-Content a.txt | ConvertTo-Xml).objects).object) | select '#text'`, but it will get complicated, if your text file is large, since you will then need to iterate through multiple child nodes.

Comment: I guess I missed something. Will check and update the thread.

Comment: @VivekKumar I tried this and something weird is showing up: $a= Get-Content a.txt;  $csv = Import-Csv $a; It fails with Could not find file C:\STATUS

Comment: That's because you don't need to import `$a`. You can directly use `$csv = Import-Csv a.txt`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160780/discussion-between-thepace-and-vivek-kumar).